# Save DropDownList SelctedValue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitefinity

I can save all values from my web page except when I save from a DDL it only saves the first or default value and not the selected value. How can I save the selected value?

Here is the code for the States DDL

```
<div>
    <label for="State" class="txtLbl">State</label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="State" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

Here is how I am saving it

```
var State = taxonomyManager.GetTaxa<FlatTaxon>().Where(t => t.Taxonomy.Name == "states").FirstOrDefault();
        if (State != null)
        {
            jobPostItem.Organizer.AddTaxa("states", State.Id);
        }
```

Here is how I am binding the DDL to the States

```
private IEnumerable<ITaxon> GetTaxonomy<TTaxonomy>(string TaxonomyName) where TTaxonomy : class, ITaxonomy
    {
        // bind categories selector
        var taxMgr = TaxonomyManager.GetManager();
        var taxonomy = taxMgr.GetTaxonomies<TTaxonomy>().Where(t => t.Title == TaxonomyName).FirstOrDefault();
        if (taxonomy == null) return null;

        // return taxa items
        var taxa = taxonomy.Taxa;
        return taxa;
    }
```

Comment: How are you binding it?  Are you binding on every page postback?  That's the most common reason the value gets wiped.

Comment: The DDL loads but saves the wrong value

Comment: Again though, can you post the code you are using to bind the dropdown in the first place too?

Comment: Usually the problem is that you set the Datasource in the PageLoad, but you should do it inside an if(!IsPostback) statement

Answer (score 0):

You should only load the values for the Dropdownlist when you are loading the page for the first time. So check for the IsPostBack property to be false.

Second, you need to enable the ViewState property on a page from within the Page Properties inside the Sitefinity backend.

That should do the trick.

Daniel

Comment: Thanks for your help Daniel. I have the "if (IsPostBack) return;" right after Page_Load and I have enabled ViewState but I still have the same issue. A lot of my code comes from this post http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/josh-morales-blog/2012/01/26/creating_dynamic_module_items_using_the_module_builder_api